# Processing request URLs from browser by the .NET Framework

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-applications

How does the .net framework know in what way the incoming URL is to be processed?

My question is not about routing mechanism within the application.

I want to know how the .net framework in the system finds out that it has to delegate the request to its MVC assemblies to route the URL to appropriate controller and action.

I hope the question is clear.

Just saw some other questions in stackoverflow and came across this link which somewhat explains i guess.
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B0_EIyBZvSQsOTU3N2Q2NDEtMWNjMS00ZTc0LWJmMjUtM2I0M2I5NDY2ZDNl/edit?pli=1

This link has detailed information
http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2008/03/18/asp-net-mvc-in-depth-the-life-of-an-asp-net-mvc-request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you host your application in IIS, then when a request comes-in, then this request is initially intercepted by IIS. Let's suppose that you hosted your application in a virtual directory called `/myapp`. When a request comes by starting with `/myapp` then IIS will handle the execution of the request to the corresponding ASP.NET pipeline. The ASP.NET pipeline will then parse the incoming request and search for corresponding managed handlers that can serve the request. If a managed handler is found that can serve the request then the processing will be passed to this handler. In the case of as ASP.NET MVC application that will be the MvcHandler which will then take care of routing and dispatching to the appropriate controller and action to serve the request.

Comment: There's no such notion as *MVC url* or *traditional webForms url*. Do you know what ASP.NET MVC is? It's a traditional ASP.NET handler. All that IIS knows about is managed ASP.NET handlers. Once it finds the appropriate handler it will pass the processing to this handler. The MvcHandler itself will know how to interpret your registered routes and which controller to instantiate and which action to call. But remember, ASP.NET MVC is nothing special. It's just a classic webForms handler which is registered to process all incoming requests. IIS doesn't know absolutely anything about ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: ASP.NET MVC is just a managed classic ASP.NET WebForms handler. ASP.NET MVC is not a special type of application itself. The host is just a classic ASP.NET application. Many people are confused into thinking that ASP.NET MVC is some special kind of thing. Not at all. It's a simple managed handler that intercepts all requests to the corresponding AppDomain and instead of rendering some classic ASPX page it passes the processing to the routing engine to pick the appropriate controller and action to be executed.

Comment: No, that's absolutely wrong. IIS doesn't know anything about routes. IIS will handle the execution to the corresponding managed handler. In the case of an MVC application that would be the `MvcHandler`. It is this handler that will take care of parsing your routes and dispatching the request to the corresponding controller. `MvcHandler` is just a normal `IHttpHandler` that anyone could have written.

Comment: Ok, now back to the original question you mentioned that IIS will handle the executio to the corresponding managed handler and in case of MVC App that would be the MvcHandler. How does IIS come to know of this? Sorry if i am asking too basic questions.

Comment: You have created a virtual directory in IIS, right? You have assigned a specific .NET Framework version to it when you configured this virtual directory, right? This virtual directory is mapped to some physical location on your hard drive, right? In this physical location you have a web.config, right? That's how it knows that it is an ASP.NET application. Remember, that's all IIS needs to know -> that it is an ASP.NET application. Then it will pass the execution to this managed application.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31827/discussion-between-ckv-and-darin-dimitrov)